# Getting Spring-XD and the hdfs sink to work for maprfs

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, mapr, spring-data-hadoop

This is a question about spring-xd release 1.0.1 working together with maprfs, which is officially not yet supported. Still I would like to get it to work.

So this is what we did:

1) adjusted the xd-shell and xd-worker and xd-singlenode shell scripts to accept the parameter `--hadoopDistro mapr`

2) added libraries to the new directory $XD_HOME/lib/mapr

```
avro-1.7.4.jar                              jersey-core-1.9.jar
hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar                jersey-server-1.9.jar
hadoop-core-1.0.3-mapr-3.0.2.jar            jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
hadoop-distcp-2.2.0.jar                     maprfs-1.0.3-mapr-3.0.2.jar
hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar                       protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar      spring-data-hadoop-2.0.2.RELEASE-hadoop24.jar
hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.jar                  spring-data-hadoop-batch-2.0.2.RELEASE-hadoop24.jar
hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar                   spring-data-hadoop-core-2.0.2.RELEASE-hadoop24.jar
hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar                spring-data-hadoop-store-2.0.2.RELEASE-hadoop24.jar
```

3) run `bin/xd-singlenode --hadoopDistro mapr` and `shell/bin/xd-shell --hadoopDistro mapr`.

When creating and deploying a stream via `stream create foo --definition "time | hdfs" --deploy`, data is written to a file tmp/xd/foo/foo-1.txt.tmp on maprfs. Yet when undeploying the stream, the following exceptions appears:

```
org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.StoreException: Failed renaming from /xd/foo/foo-1.txt.tmp to /xd/foo/foo-1.txt; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Requested file /xd/foo/foo-1.txt does not exist.
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.OutputStoreObjectSupport.renameFile(OutputStoreObjectSupport.java:261)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.output.TextFileWriter.close(TextFileWriter.java:92)
at org.springframework.xd.integration.hadoop.outbound.HdfsDataStoreMessageHandler.doStop(HdfsDataStoreMessageHandler.java:58)
at org.springframework.xd.integration.hadoop.outbound.HdfsStoreMessageHandler.stop(HdfsStoreMessageHandler.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.stop(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer.doStop(EventDrivenConsumer.java:64)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.stop(AbstractEndpoint.java:100)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.stop(AbstractEndpoint.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.stop(ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.java:303)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:229)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$300(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:363)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:106)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.stop(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1186)
at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.stop(SimpleModule.java:234)
at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.destroyModule(ModuleDeployer.java:132)
at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.handleUndeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:111)
at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.undeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:83)
at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar.undeployModule(ContainerRegistrar.java:261)
at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar$StreamModuleWatcher.process(ContainerRegistrar.java:884)
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceWatcher.process(NamespaceWatcher.java:67)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:522)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Requested file /xd/foo/foo-1.txt does not exist.
at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.getMapRFileStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:805)
at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.delete(MapRFileSystem.java:629)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.store.support.OutputStoreObjectSupport.renameFile(OutputStoreObjectSupport.java:258)
... 29 more
```

I had a look at the `OutputStoreObjectSupport.renameFile()` function. When a file on hdfs is finished, this method tries to rename the file /xd/foo/foo-1.txt.tmp to xd/foo/foo1.txt. This is the relevant code:

```
        try {
        FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(getConfiguration());

        boolean succeed;
        try {
            fs.delete(toPath, false);
            log.info("Renaming path=[" + path + "] toPath=[" + toPath + "]");
            succeed = fs.rename(path, toPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new StoreException("Failed renaming from " + path + " to " + toPath, e);
        }
        if (!succeed) {
            throw new StoreException("Failed renaming from " + path + " to " + toPath + " because hdfs returned false");
        }
    }
```

When the target file does not exist on hdfs, maprfs seems to throw an exception when `fs.delete(toPath, false)` is called. Yet throwing an exception in this case does not make sense. I assume that other Filesystem implementations behave differently, but this is a point I still need to verify. Unfortuntately I cannot find the sources for MapRFileSystem.java. Is this closed source? This would help me to better understand the issue. Has anybody experience with writing from spring-xd to maprfs? Or renaming files on maprfs with spring-data-hadoop?

#### Edit

I managed to reproduce the issue outside of spring XD with a simple test case (see below). Note that this exception is only thrown if the inWritingSuffix or the inWritingPrefix is set. Otherwise spring-hadoop will not attempt to rename the file. So this is the still somehow unsatisfactory workaround for me: refrain from using inWritingPrefixes and inWritingSuffixes.

```
@ContextConfiguration("context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MaprfsSinkTest {

    @Autowired 
    Configuration configuration;

    @Autowired
    FileSystem filesystem;

    @Autowired 
    DataStoreWriter<String >storeWriter;

    @Test
    public void testRenameOnMaprfs() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Path testPath = new Path("/tmp/foo.txt");
        filesystem.delete(testPath, true);
        TextFileWriter writer = new TextFileWriter(configuration, testPath, null);
        writer.setInWritingSuffix("tmp");
        writer.write("some entity");
        writer.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStoreWriter() throws IOException {
        this.storeWriter.write("something");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new branch for spring-hadoop which supports maprfs:

https://github.com/blinse/spring-hadoop/tree/origin/2.0.2.RELEASE-mapr

Building this release and using the resulting jar works fine with the hdfs sink.